# Error: spawn lame ENOENT

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mp3

Estoy tratando de reducir la Memoria de un audio grabado de un MP3, debido a que 3 segundos pesan 600kb lo cual considero bastante pesado para que el Servidor lo Soporte. Estoy intentando con una Libreria para convertir de MP3 a otro MP3 pero mas minificado, pero me lanza el siguiente error, usando la libreria node-lame.

```
Error: spawn lame ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn lame',
  path: 'lame',
  spawnargs: [
```

Comment: ENOENT significa que nodejs no pudo encontrar un "archivo", podría se que no esté instalado instalado node-lame para poder utilizarlo o tengas un error en el path del cual lo importas. Fíjate si esto https://github.com/devowlio/node-lame/issues/6 te ayuda a resolver tu problema.

Comment: En realidad un mp3 es básicamente un formato muy comprimido, generalmente es complejo bajar su tamaño, lo que si se puede hacer es jugar con el CBR y su amplitud, ejemplo, para una web no deberías necesitar 192Kbps stereo ni 24bits, o sea podrías tranquilamente desde cualquier conversor de windows reducirlos a 64 o 128kbps, mono y en 16 bits y tendrías una diferencia sustancial de tamaño seguramente.

Comment: @Asero82 Ya lo intente, lo instale en Windows y configure las Variables de Entorno pero aun asi me sigue sacando el mismo error.